"des" und "das" im Wienerischen
Im Wienerischen Dialekt wird der Artikel "das" manchmal als "des" und manchmal als "das" ausgesprochen.
Ich habe mal eine grammatische Erklärung gehört, habe diese aber wieder vergessen. Daher suche ich jetzt Informationen darüber.

Der Artikel "das" wird immer als "des" ausgesprochen. Anders übrigens als "daß" (oder "damit"), welches zu "doss" oder "dass" wird. Für nicht-native Sprecher ist da die Verwechslungsgefahr groß, insbesondere, weil der Wiener Dialekt einen Hang zur Lenisierung hat und "dass" manchmal eher wie "das" ausgesprochen wird.

Das(s) i amoi so oid wia!

"Daß ich einmal so alt werde, [glaube ich nicht]/[hätte ich nicht geglaubt]!"
Hingegen:

Nau wüs'd, dos's geht?

"Na, willst du, daß es funktioniert?"
Es ist allerdings auch so, daß die Sprecher des Wiener Dialekts die Eigenart haben, zu Betonungszwecken (aber nach Regeln, die ausgesprochen schwierig zu erklären und für Nichtmuttersprachler kaum nachvollziehbar sind) in die Hochsprache - und wieder zurück - wechseln. Dieser Wechsel kann durchaus auch mitten im Satz vollzogen werden. Das klingt dann etwa so:

Wauns'd mi frogst, das Leben ... is schwa wuan!

"Wenn du mich fragst, das Leben ist schwer geworden", aber mit besonderer Betonung auf "das Leben". Der Sprecher nimmt dabei in Anspruch, eine besondere existenzielle Erkenntnis von philosophischer Tragweite auszusprechen. Hätte der Sprecher lediglich das Faktum anmerken wollen, im Sinne von "die Zeiten sind schwierig", dann hätte das eher so geklungen:

S'Lem is schwa wuan.

Diese Eigenart, den unvermittelten Wechsel in die Hochsprache und zurück, findet man etwa in den Stücken Johann Nepomuk Nestroys, sie kommt aber auch in der täglich gesprochenen Sprache regelmäßig vor. Genauso bedient sich Karl Kraus dieses Stilmittels im Drama Die letzten Tage der Menschheit, um bestimmte Sphären darzustellen.

Die Antwort von bakunin ist zwar größtenteils richtig, ich muss ihm aber in einem Punkt widersprechen: Die Version [doːs] hört man zwar tatsächlich in seltenen Situationen, viel häufiger sind aber [deːs] für den Artikel das und für das Pronomen das sowie [daːs] und [das] für die Subjunktion dass.
Als Beispiel dafür möchte den Liedtext von Wem gheard des Mensch? vom Wiener Dialekt-Liedermacher Voodoo Jürgens anführen:

Sog mia no, wem gheard des1 Mensch?
Des2 mit an Oasch auf drei Kiatog taunzt,
den gaunzn Tog herumstrawanzt,
n Steckalfisch ois a Gaunza mampft.
De4 soll aufhearn, dass3 so grausliche Lieder singt,
wɶ7 sunst wieder a Bua von da Bruckn springt.
Sog mia no, wem gheard des Mensch?
Des Zinkn in die5 Martal ritzt,
die6 olle siebn Zwetschkn isst,
dem Nochbarn auf die Blumen bischt.
De soll aufhearn, dass so grausliche Lieder singt,
wɶ sunst wieder a Bua von da Bruckn springt.
Sog mia no, wem gheard des Mensch?
Des auf da Friedhofsmauer hockt.
Schauts ihr bessa ned untan Rock,
wɶs eich sunst die Urwaschln owebrockt.
De soll aufhearn, dass so grausliche Lieder singt,
wɶ sunst wieder a Bua von da Bruckn springt.
Sog mia no, wem gheard des Mensch?
Des unsre liabn Buam vazaht,
die eahna wos ins Drangl laat.
Wonn die nua wea kenna dad, kenna dad!
De soll aufhearn, dass so grausliche Lieder singt,
wɶ sunst wieder a Bua von da Bruckn springt.

(Kommentierte Übersetzung ins Standarddeutsche am Ende meiner Antwort)
1 Des Mensch = das Mädchen. Hier ist »das« ein bestimmter Artikel, und dieser Artikel wird im Wiener Dialekt als »des« ausgesprochen.
2 »Des Mensch, des taunzt.« = »Das Mädchen, das tanzt.« Das fett hervorgehobene »das« ist ein Relativpronomen, das einen Relativsatz einleitet und durch welche ersetzt werden könnte. Dieses Pronomen wird im Wiener Dialekt ebenfalls zu »des«.
3 »De soll aufhearn, dass singt« = »Die soll aufhören, dass (sie) singt.« Das fett hervorgehobene Wort ist eine Subjunktion, die im Standarddeutschen genau gleich ausgesprochen wird wie der Artikel und wie das Pronomen, aber im Wiener Dialekt verwendet man dafür eine andere Aussprache, nämlich [daːs] (mit langem a) oder [das] (mit kurzem a, so wie auch im Hochdeutschen). Einige Sprecher bevorzugen die Version mit einem langen a, andere die Version mit kurzem a, und eine dritte Gruppe von Sprechern wechselt zwischen beiden Versionen.
Der Satzbau »Die soll aufhören, dass sie singt« ist im Standarddeutschen nicht üblich, stattdessen würde man eine Konstruktion mit zu + Infinitiv verwenden: »Die soll aufhören, zu singen«, dabei würde aber die Subjunktion dass verschwinden, um die es hier aber geht. Im Dialektsatz fehlt im Dass-Satz scheinbar auch das Subjekt »sie«, aber dieses »sie« wird im Dialekt zum Affix »'s«, das an das vorangehende Wort angefügt wird: »Wie sie meinen« = »Wia's mana.« Wenn das vorangehende Wort aber mit einem S endet, verschmilzt das angehängte »'s« komplett mit dem Vorgängerwort und verschwindet auf diese Weise: »... dass sie singt« → »... dass's singt« → »... dass singt«
Oft wird behauptet, dass der Artikel, das Pronomen oder die Subjunktion wie »dos« ausgesprochen werden, aber außer in Parodien des Wiener Dialekts ist mir diese Aussprache bisher noch bei keinem Sprecher aufgefallen. (Ich habe von 1997 bis 2015 in Wien gelebt und lebe seit 2024 wieder in dieser wunderbaren Stadt.)

Unterschiedliche Aussprachen im Dialekt bei standardsprachlichen Homophonen, findet man auch bei anderen  Wörtern, zum Beispiel beim Wort »die«, das standarddeutsch ein Artikel, ein Relativpronomen oder ein (abwertendes) Personalpronomen sein kann:
4 »De soll aufhearn.« = »Die soll aufhören.« Das Personalpronomen »die« wird im Wiener Dialekt zu »de«.
5 »Die Marterl« = »Die Bildstöcke« (später im Text auch: »die Blumen« = »die Blumen«). Der bestimmte Artikel »die« ist auch im Dialekt »die«.
6 »Des Mensch, des ritzt, die isst.« = »Das Mädchen, das ritzt, die isst.« Auch das Relativpronomen »die« bleibt im Dialekt »die«. (Hier ist auch zu beobachten, dass das sächliche Substantiv Mensch, das eine weibliche Person bezeichnet, zuerst mit einem sächlichen Relativpronomen referenziert wird, im zweiten Relativsatz aber mit einem weiblichen Relativpronomen. So einen Wechsel vom grammatikalischen zum biologischen Geschlecht kann man zunehmend auch im Standarddeutschen beobachten.)

7 Das Zeichen ɶ steht hier für eine sehr offenen langen Laut zwischen a und ö, der, wenn er kurz gesprochen wird, im Standarddeutschen mit ö (»Hölle«) verschriftlicht wird. Im Standarddeutschen existiert dieser Laut aber nur als kurzer Laut (das lange ö in »Höhle« ist ein anderer Laut), aber in bairischen Dialekten werden e und ei vor l häufig als lange Version des Hölle-Ös gesprochen, die im Standarddeutschen nicht existiert. (Daher auch: Schellen-Ast → Schölnast)

Kommentierte Übersetzung des Liedtextes ins Standarddeutsche

Sag mir doch, wer ist dieses böse/unartige Mädchen? Wörtlich: »... wem gehört dieses Mensch?« »Das Mensch« (Plural: »die Menscher«, im Dialekt manchmal auch »das Mendsch, die Mendscher«) ist ein sehr alter abwertender Ausdruck für ein Mädchen oder eine junge Frau.
Das mit ihrem Hintern auf drei Kirtagen tanzt, Kirtag = Dorffest. »Auf mehreren Kirtagen tanzen« = »überall mit dabei sein«; im vorliegenden Kontext auch »bei jedem Unsinn mitmachen«
sich den ganzen Tag umhertreibt, strawanzen = sich herumtreiben, nicht arbeiten, ein unstetes Leben führen. Ein Strawanzer ist eine zwielichtige Gestalt und/oder ein Kleinkrimineller.
(und) den Steckerfisch im Ganzen verschlingt. Steckerlfisch ist ein auf einem Holzspieß (Steckerl = kleiner Stecken) gegrillter Fisch. Hier wird darauf angespielt, dass sie gern große längliche Körperteile in den Mund nimmt.
Die soll aufhören, den ganzen Tag so abscheuliche Lieder zu singen, grauslich = abscheulich, ekelhaft; im vorliegenden Kontext aber auch obszön.
Weil sonst wieder ein Junge von der Brücke springt.
Sag mir doch, wer ist dieses böse/unartige Mädchen?
das Kerben in die Bildstöcke ritzt, »Zinke« = »Kerbe« im vorliegenden Kontext (z.B. gezinkte Karten sind Karten mit kleinen fühlbaren Kerben am Rand). Marterln sind christliches Flurdenkmäler, die vor allem in Österreich und Bayern in ländlichen Gebieten zu finden sind. Solche religiösen Denkmäler zu verunstalten ist in Österreich eine Straftat, für die man gleich zweimal bestraft wird (§125 und §188 StGB).
die alle sieben Pflaumen isst, Streng genommen sind Zwetschken (in Deutschland auch: Zwetschgen) eine Unterart der Pflaumen. »Sieben Zwetschken« ist auch ein Synonym für »Habseligkeiten« oder Siebensachen (»Pack deine sieben Zwetschken« = »Pack deine Siebensachen«). Mit »sieben Zwetschken« können je nach Kontext, hier aber mit Bestimmtheit, auch die Geschlechtsorgane gemeint sein.
(und) dem Nachbarn auf die Blumen pinkelt.
Die soll aufhören, den ganzen Tag so abscheuliche Lieder zu singen,
Weil sonst wieder ein Junge von der Brücke springt.
Sag mir doch, wer ist dieses böse/unartige Mädchen?
Das auf der Friedhofsmauer hockt.
Guckt ihr lieber nicht unter den Rock,
weil sie euch sonst die Ohren abreißt. »Ohrwaschl« = »Ohrenmuschel«, als der Teil des Ohres, der außerhalb des Schädels liegt. »Etwas brocken« = »etwas pflücken« (Äpfel brocken = Äpfel pflücken). Die Vorsilbe »owe« in »owebrockn« bedeutet »herunter« (»herunterpflücken«).
Die soll aufhören, den ganzen Tag so abscheuliche Lieder zu singen,
Weil sonst wieder ein Junge von der Brücke springt.
Sag mir doch, wer ist dieses böse/unartige Mädchen?
Das unsere lieben Jungs verschleppt,
die ihnen etwas ins Getränk leert.
Wenn die bloß jemand kennen würde, kennen würde!
Die soll aufhören, den ganzen Tag so abscheuliche Lieder zu singen,
Weil sonst wieder ein Junge von der Brücke springt.


Ich finde es amüsant, daß nach dem Widerspruch in der Einleitung genau die Behauptung kommt, die ich selbst aufgestellt habe: hochdeutsches "das" (Artikel, Relativpronomen) wird zu "des", hochdeutsches "daß" (Konjunktion) wird, je nachdem, zu "dass" oder "doss" (eigentlich: "dåss"), wobei die scharf gesprochenen Auslaute auch lenisiert werden können, sodaß "dos" bzw. "das" entsteht. Beispiel für unterlassene Lenisierung etwa in "dass di da Teife hoi" oder Relativsätzen, in denen auf "daß" ein "es" folgt, das im Dialekt dann mit der Konjunktion zusammengezogen wird.

"Das mit ihrem Hintern auf drei Kirtagen tanzt," diese Übersetzung ist falsch! "Mit aan Oasch auf drei Kirtog daunzn" bedeutet: mit einem Hintern auf drei Kirtagen zu tanzen! Der Sinn der Redewendung besteht ja eben darin, daß man (und damit auch der eigene Hintern) immer nur auf einem Dorffest zugleich sein kann.

@bakunin: Mir fällt gerade auf, dass der Oasch auch eine unsympatische männliche Person sein könnte. Das würde sogar besser in den Kontext passen. Aber es ging in der Frage nicht um diese Übersetzung, daher werde ich meine Erstfassung nicht ändern.

Der Oasch ist sicher keine "unsympathische männliche Person", sondern ein literales Hinterteil in dieser Redewendung, die man nämlich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch für Personen jeden Geschlechts gebraucht, im Sinne von "Hans-Dampf-in-allen-Gassen-spielen" bzw, in der Verneinung "I kau ned mit aan Oasch auf drei Kirtog daunzn" im Sinne von "ich kann nicht überall gleichzeitig sein". Ob Du in Deinen Antworten falsche Behauptungen aufstellen willst oder nicht, überlasse ich Deiner Entscheidung.
